# Hide a div based on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, html

I am trying to hide a div whenever someone goes to a specific url.

Something like this:

```
var url = document.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp') >= 0) {
    $('#hidebox').hide();
} else {
    $('#hidebox').show();
}

write("<div id=\"hidebox\">\n");
write("<p>test</p>\n");
write("</div>\n");
```

Comment: make sure that this gets run after hidebox has been rendered

Comment: Could you show us your HTML code as well?

Comment: We're going to need more information. For example, is the code above running in the `.ready()` event handler (to know, we'll need to see the full JS)? Does **hidebox** realy exist in the markup (to know, we'll need to see the markup).

Comment: Both the JS script and the div are in a asp include file.

Comment: write("<div id=\"hidebox\">\n");
                                 write("<p>test</p>\n");
                                 write("</div>\n");

Comment: @Matt Stone - Couldn't you match on the `loginfull.asp` value only?

Comment: jared i tried that too.. i don't understand why this isn't working.. hiding a div on a certain url shouldn't be that hard to do lol

Answer (score 2):

Run your code after the page is loaded and the element to hide is available to jQuery. Also convert the url into lower case and compare in case user types in mixed cases.

```
$(function(){
     var url = document.location.href;

     if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp') >= 0) {
       $('#hidebox').hide();
     } else {
        $('#hidebox').show();
     }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the url is matching?

Comment: Ok i set this up on a test page so you guys could see what im talking about http://www.donorperfect.com/asp/loginfull_matt.asp... up near the header you will see the word "test-this is the hidebox div"..

Comment: I see its hidden on page load.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Going off of the link that you provided as an example, there are several issues here.

1. Your `SCRIPT` tag should be in the `HEAD` block
2. You are using `$()` when it is not available (Firebug gives a clear error on this)
3. The file name does not match your `indexOf()` match

Fixing these issues, it works fine. See:

```
<head>
...
<script language='JavaScript' src='/js/jquery-1.4.1.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; 

    if (url.indexOf('donorperfect.html') > -1) { 
        $('#hidebox').show();
    } else { 
        $('#hidebox').hide();  
    } 
});
</script>
...
</head>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/donorperfect.html

The following code works (`setTimeout` is for demonstration purposes):

```
document.write("<div id=\"hidebox\">\n");
document.write("<p>test</p>\n");
document.write("</div>\n");

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp';

    if (url.indexOf('http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp') > -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){$('#hidebox').hide()},2000);
    } else {
        $('#hidebox').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Qt8uH/

Although this is probably what I would recommend (for instance, what happens if it's `HTTPS`?):

```
document.write("<div id=\"hidebox\">\n");
document.write("<p>test</p>\n");
document.write("</div>\n");

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp';

    if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('loginfull.asp') > -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){$('#hidebox').hide()},2000);
    } else {
        $('#hidebox').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Qt8uH/1/

Comment: write("<sc"+"ript type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"JavaScript\">\n");
 write("$(function(){\n");
 write(" var url = 'http://www.donorperfect.com/asp/loginfull_matt.asp';//window.location.pathname;\n");
 write(" if (url.indexOf('loginfull.asp') >= 0) { \n");
 write(" $('#hidebox').hide(); \n");
 write("} else {\n");
 write("$('#hidebox').show(); \n");
 write("} else {\n");
 write(" }\n");
 write("});\n");
 write("</sc"+"ript>\n");

Comment: from this page http://jfcoder.com/test/donorperfect.html and it still wasn't working

Comment: One of my last edits was a wrong (I copied the wrong code). So if it didn't work, try it again.

Comment: And you're still making a fundamental mistake: Your URL is `loginfull_matt.asp`, but you are trying to hide `if url.indexOf('loginfull.asp')`. For your test, this should be `if (url.indexOf('loginfull_matt.asp') > -1)`

Comment: i tried it again if you look on my test page http://www.donorperfect.com/asp/loginfull_matt.asp..because the way they have the code written i have to write the JS out with the write commands as below.. So unless i have that wrong?


write("<sc"+"ript type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"JavaScript\">\n");
 write("$(function(){\n");
 write("  if (url.indexOf('loginfull.asp') > -1) {  \n");
 write(" $('#hidebox').hide(); \n");
 write("} else {\n");
 write("$('#hidebox').show(); \n");
 write("} else {\n");
 write(" }\n");
 write("});\n");
 write("</sc"+"ript>\n")

Comment: And also your code syntax is not right: `} else { $('#hidebox').show(); } else { }` The second `else` should not be there. Are you using FF Firebug or Chrome Console?

Comment: ahh yes i just caught that mistake.. but even after i fixed the code to: (url.indexOf('loginfull_matt.asp') > -1) is still didnt make it disappear

Comment: I'm still seeing it at that link. Are you using a console to review errors?

Comment: You forgot to add back `var url = window.location.href;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing `document.location.href` to `window.location.pathname;`

So your code now says

```
var url = window.location.pathname; 

    if (url.indexOf('http://donorperfect.local/asp/loginfull.asp') >= 0) { 
     $('#hidebox').hide(); 
     } else { 
     $('#hidebox').show(); 
     }
```

Comment: @Matt: Instead of just saying "it doesn't work" or "it was a no go" all the time, can you tell us what _did_ happen? Do some debugging!

Comment: Tomalak - when i say no go. or it doesnt work i mean that nothing happened. The div didn't disappear and there was no errors

Comment: @Matt Stone - You should probably try using some `console.log()` calls in your if block to make sure it's working the way you expect.

Comment: I just realised that it should be document.location.href, not the .pathname one, so ignore the previous answer. I'd recommend going to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to try different solutions. I noticed you're using a 'write' statement to generate the DIV. If that's the case, might as well call the statement only if the url.indexOf is true.

Comment: Ok i set this up on a test page so you guys could see what im talking about http://www.donorperfect.com/asp/loginfull_matt.asp

Comment: @Matt - That should be part of the question text, not a comment in an answer.

Comment: The <script> tag should be somewhere within the <head> tag, definitely after the jquery file call!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!!! Try this. it grabs the URL from the address bar.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/continueSearch.asp?categoryID=108") {
    $('#website').html('<p>This is the Apartments Category page</p>');
} else {
    $('#website').hide();
}});
```

if not .hide();. try .empty();